# php - construct by both parent and child

Tags: php, parent-child, subclass, parent, construct

I want to make such thing in php:
I want to have the parent class named "item", and a bunch of child classes like "sword", "armor" etc.
I can call simply:

```
$some_sword = new sword($id) ;
```

But I also want to do sth like this:

```
$some_sword = new item("sword",$id) ;
```

And I want both codes do he same effect. $some_sword must be the same class in both ways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the new keyword will always return an instance of the class in question. however you can use a static method in the parent to return child class object (or any objects for that matter).

```
class Item
{
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        //Whatever
    }

    /**
     * Gets the object requested and passes the ID
     *
     * @param string object to return
     * @param integer id
     * @return object
     */
    public static function get($itemtype, $id)
    {
        $classname = ucfirst($itemtype);
        return new $classname($id);
    }
}

class Sword extends Item
{
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        //Whatever
    }
}

class Armor extends Item
{
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        //Whatever
    }
}

// Client Code
$some_sword = Item::get('sword', 1);
$some_armor = Item::get('armor', 2);
```

Comment: Edited to fix a bug in the get method (i really should test my code before i post it!)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be suitable enough :D

Comment: Do you think you could possibly make it the accepted answer? it would mean an awful lot :)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. You see I am new to stackoverflow. Just made your answer accepted, thx.